# How to get SugerCRM Menu Item

Tags: android, sugarcrm

Im very new to sugerCRM `http://url/service/v4_1/rest.php`.It has 36 methods to call.which method shall i call to get the Main menu items assign to user?like Account,Call,Contact etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268943/how-to-get-sugercrm-menu-item)

as Documentation -

`get_available_modules` - Retrieves a list of available modules in the system.